# how to use webauthn-json to encode

Tags: webauthn

I am trying to implement webauthn in a rails application, I'm trying to follow along with this github repo:

https://github.com/cedarcode/webauthn-ruby

I have the server challenge working great, it gets sent to the browser:

```
options = WebAuthn::Credential.options_for_create(
        user: { id: current_user.webauthn_id, name: current_user.email },
        exclude: current_user.credentials.map { |c| c.webauthn_id }
    )

    # Store the newly generated challenge somewhere so you can have it
    # for the verification phase.
    session[:creation_challenge] = options.challenge
    binding.pry
    render json: options
```

Now, on the browser side (in javascript), I am trying to do:

```
navigator.credentials.create({"publickey": window.webauthn_options})
```

(note, i store the options from the controller in the window variable), but when I do this, I get a browser console error:

```
TypeError: CredentialsContainer.create: Missing required 'challenge' member of PublicKeyCredentialCreationOptions.
```

In the debugger, I see that challenge does indeed exist, but I am guessing this has to do with some kind of encoding issue. There is a really vague reference about base64url encoding and using this repo to encode / decode:

https://github.com/github/webauthn-json/

But I don't have any idea how to use this, it seems like it's a nodejs package (?) I was expecting a javascript file (I'm not a node programmer). So I guess my questions are:

1) how does one use a node js package (not sure if this repo is that, just guessing) to make a js file that I can deploy to a server in a rails application?

2) Is it correct that this error means that even though the challenge is there, it's not encoded properly?

Thanks for any help,
Kevin

UPDATE

Thanks for the great answer @mackie, the fido site has a lot of useful stuff, and their js helped a lot, adding that here in case future webauthn devs need huge time saver:

https://www.passwordless.dev/js/mfa.register.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Managing the transition between server and client and ensuring everything is the correct type is a little bit of a pain but the below example works for me. I used the sample provided by https://github.com/abergs/fido2-net-lib and found it very useful.

Below is an example JSON data structure (with base64url encoded values for the properties that WebAuthn specifies as ArrayBuffers, I've also shortened the pubKeyCredParams array) returned by my second factor credential create options server endpoint:

```
{
    "rp": {
        "id": "localhost",
        "name": "IDS4"
    },
    "user": {
        "name": "joe.bloggs@acme.com",
        "id": "YTNmZTAxYWUtODlhYS00NDEzLTgxYzQtZWJmZjk0MmI5MTVj",
        "displayName": "Your ACME account"
    },
    "challenge": "P8_m1vd5tcMDD9e0SeST4w",
    "pubKeyCredParams": [
        {
            "type": "public-key",
            "alg": -7
        }
    ],
    "timeout": 60000,
    "attestation": "indirect",
    "authenticatorSelection": {
        "authenticatorAttachment": "cross-platform",
        "requireResidentKey": false,
        "userVerification": "discouraged"
    },
    "excludeCredentials": [
        {
            "type": "public-key",
            "id": "A_IySAe38xFIoTUbAFyAUIrgawhcPOD_xbBDf_UqkvJc_GR37-jRXccYE04A5CmhA3kG8WTGPZP63MiQQ2ykDQ"
        }
    ],
    "extensions": {
        "exts": true,
        "uvi": true,
        "loc": true,
        "uvm": true,
        "biometricPerfBounds": {
            "FAR": 3.4028235E+38,
            "FRR": 3.4028235E+38
        }
    }
}
```

The values that need coercing to an ArrayBuffer are:

- `challenge`
- `user`.`id`
- `excludeCredentials`[`n`].`id`

Helper functions - WebAuthnHelpers.js:

```
class WebAuthnHelpers {
    static coerceToArrayBuffer(input) {
        if (typeof input === "string") {
            // base64url to base64
            input = input.replace(/-/g, "+").replace(/_/g, "/");

            // base64 to Uint8Array
            var str = window.atob(input);
            var bytes = new Uint8Array(str.length);
            for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
                bytes[i] = str.charCodeAt(i);
            }
            input = bytes;
        }

        // Array to Uint8Array
        if (Array.isArray(input)) {
            input = new Uint8Array(input);
        }

        // Uint8Array to ArrayBuffer
        if (input instanceof Uint8Array) {
            input = input.buffer;
        }

        // error if none of the above worked
        if (!(input instanceof ArrayBuffer)) {
            throw new TypeError("could not coerce '" + name + "' to ArrayBuffer");
        }

        return input;
    }

    static coerceToBase64Url(input) {
        // Array or ArrayBuffer to Uint8Array
        if (Array.isArray(input)) {
            input = Uint8Array.from(input);
        }

        if (input instanceof ArrayBuffer) {
            input = new Uint8Array(input);
        }

        // Uint8Array to base64
        if (input instanceof Uint8Array) {
            var str = "";
            var len = input.byteLength;

            for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                str += String.fromCharCode(input[i]);
            }
            input = window.btoa(str);
        }

        if (typeof input !== "string") {
            throw new Error("could not coerce to string");
        }

        // base64 to base64url
        // NOTE: "=" at the end of challenge is optional, strip it off here
        input = input.replace(/\+/g, "-").replace(/\//g, "_").replace(/=*$/g, "");

        return input;
    }
}
```

e.g.

```
credentialCreateOptions.challenge = WebAuthnHelpers.coerceToArrayBuffer(credentialCreateOptions.challenge);

credentialCreateOptions.user.id = WebAuthnHelpers.coerceToArrayBuffer(credentialCreateOptions.user.id);

credentialCreateOptions.excludeCredentials = credentialCreateOptions.excludeCredentials.map((c) =>
{
    c.id = WebAuthnHelpers.coerceToArrayBuffer(c.id);
    return c;
});

if (credentialCreateOptions.authenticatorSelection.authenticatorAttachment === null) credentialCreateOptions.authenticatorSelection.authenticatorAttachment = undefined;
```

Once that is done I can pass `credentialCreateOptions` directly to `navigator.credentials.create`({`publicKey`: ... })

Comment: thanks so much, is there an analagous helper js to encode the credentials returned from navigator.credentials.create, or is that what coerceToBase64Url is for?

Comment: disregard, i found the js i needed on the fido site, thanks again

Comment: Glad you sorted it :)

Comment: do you mind having a look at a follow up question @mackie : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61798641/webauthn-authentication-javascript-formatting-assistance

Comment: @user1130176 responded :)

Comment: thanks @mackie ! Couldn't make it work with github-json either...